# How to protect project file in ubuntu server?

Tags: 16.04, server, virtualbox, xubuntu, kubuntu

We have ubuntu server 18.04 installed. We want our team to work their project from the server only so that they cannot save the file in their local pc. Is it feasible to make it work in that way. If above questions seems to unclear then lets me make clear from the following example.

Assume that we have three guys on team namely A, B and C. A works for software development, B works for Mobile Development and C works for database development. Now we want all this guys (a,b and c) able to work from our server so that they cannot take that file at home or share to anyone or able to save either in their own personal local pc. Is it feasible to make the team work in that way ? Please advise

Comment: I don't that is possible better create a group and add those guys to it. In the end you need to hire trusted people!

Answer (score 0):

> Now we want all this guys (a,b and c) able to work from our server so that they cannot take that file at home or share to anyone or able to save either in their own personal local pc. Is it feasible to make the team work in that way ? Please advise

No. To quote Bruce Schneier:

> Digital files cannot be made uncopyable, any more than water can be made not wet.

This is always true. They can copy the text, or they can snap a photo of the monitor and do an OCR of the code. If they can view it, you have to assume that they can copy it.

If that is not OK, you should hire programmers you can trust.

If you have high security requirements, you may require that the coders surrender cell phones and other devices before entering a secure compartment, where they will use a computer that they can't plug USB devices into...